# Avoid Duplicate entry error

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, scrapy

I'm using `MySQLdb`to insert records in my database, I created a table with an `UNIQUE KEY` on the `domain field`.

I would like to avoid the error : `IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry 'xxxxx.com' for key 'domain'")`.

How can I do that ?

**My code is here :**

```
try:
    CONN = MySQLdb.connect(host=SQL_HOST,
                           user=SQL_USER,
                           passwd=SQL_PASSWD,
                           db=SQL_DB)
except MySQLdb.Error, e:
    print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
    sys.exit(1)

cursor = CONN.cursor()

def insert_table(domain, trust_flow, citation_flow, ref_domains, ext_back_links):
    sql = "INSERT INTO %s (domain, TrustFlow, CitationFlow, RefDomains, ExtBackLinks) values('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')" % (SQL_TABLE, domain, trust_flow, citation_flow, ref_domains, ext_back_links)
    if cursor.execute(sql):
        CONN.commit()
```

Comment: Stop inserting records that have the same value as existing records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [INSERT ... ON DUPLCATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

```
INSERT INTO %s (domain, TrustFlow, CitationFlow, RefDomains, ExtBackLinks) values('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE TrustFlow = VALUES(TrustFlow), CitationFlow = VALUES(CitationFlow) ....
```